# Haproxy http-check string can't access mysqld-exporter metrics after go runtime ones

Tags: metrics, haproxy

I try to setup HAproxy http-check and it fails to work with mariadb_exporter metrics list:

```
    backend galera-nodes
      mode tcp
      option srvtcpka
      option httpchk GET /metrics
      #http-check expect string go_threads <- this one works as last one from list
      # http-check expect string mysql_engine_innodb_read_views_open_inside_innodb < this one is broken and it's first metric not from go runtime metrics      
      http-check expect string mysql_global_variables_wsrep_on\ 1 # I want this one to work, but it doesn't want to for some reason
      balance first

      default-server init-addr none check resolvers mydns
      server node-0 mariadb-0.mariadb.test-mariadb.svc.cluster.local:3306 check port 9104
      server node-1 mariadb-1.mariadb.test-mariadb.svc.cluster.local:3306 check port 9104 backup
      server node-2 mariadb-2.mariadb.test-mariadb.svc.cluster.local:3306 check port 9104 backup
```

Problem is quite interesting because I can acces top-from-list metrics regarding go runtime, example:

```
# HELP go_gc_cycles_automatic_gc_cycles_total Count of completed GC cycles generated by the Go runtime.
# TYPE go_gc_cycles_automatic_gc_cycles_total counter
go_gc_cycles_automatic_gc_cycles_total 148211
# HELP go_gc_cycles_forced_gc_cycles_total Count of completed GC cycles forced by the application.
# TYPE go_gc_cycles_forced_gc_cycles_total counter
go_gc_cycles_forced_gc_cycles_total 0
```

I can't acces anything after guages, blocking on metric mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error, example:

```
# HELP go_threads Number of OS threads created.
# TYPE go_threads gauge
go_threads 10
# HELP mysql_engine_innodb_read_views_open_inside_innodb Read views open inside InnoDB.
# TYPE mysql_engine_innodb_read_views_open_inside_innodb gauge
mysql_engine_innodb_read_views_open_inside_innodb 0
# HELP mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds Collector time duration.
# TYPE mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds gauge
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.engine_innodb_status"} 0.000647209
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.global_status"} 0.006044561
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.global_variables"} 0.010484458
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.info_schema.innodb_cmp"} 0.000210445
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.info_schema.innodb_cmpmem"} 0.000821883
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.info_schema.query_response_time"} 0.010943727
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.slave_status"} 0.000288631
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="connection"} 0.00164831
# HELP mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error Whether the last scrape of metrics from MySQL resulted in an error (1 for error, 0 for success).
# TYPE mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error gauge-
mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error 0 #### <--- this one is inaccessible
```

go_threads works, mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds works, every metric below is broken (verified it using random metrics)

I can't see any broken/special characters:

```
# HELP go_threads Number of OS threads created.^M$
# TYPE go_threads gauge^M$
go_threads 10^M$
# HELP mysql_engine_innodb_read_views_open_inside_innodb Read views open inside InnoDB.^M$
# TYPE mysql_engine_innodb_read_views_open_inside_innodb gauge^M$
mysql_engine_innodb_read_views_open_inside_innodb 0^M$
# HELP mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds Collector time duration.^M$
# TYPE mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds gauge^M$
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.engine_innodb_status"} 0.000566157^M$
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.global_status"} 0.005119717^M$
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.global_variables"} 0.010971451^M$
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.info_schema.innodb_cmp"} 0.000200721^M$
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.info_schema.innodb_cmpmem"} 0.000738683^M$
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.info_schema.query_response_time"} 0.011611622^M$
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="collect.slave_status"} 0.011444507^M$
mysql_exporter_collector_duration_seconds{collector="connection"} 0.001675709^M$
# HELP mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error Whether the last scrape of metrics from MySQL resulted in an error (1 for error, 0 for success).^M$
# TYPE mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error gauge^M$
mysql_exporter_last_scrape_error 0^M$
# HELP mysql_exporter_scrapes_total Total number of times MySQL was scraped for metrics.^M$
# TYPE mysql_exporter_scrapes_total counter^M$
mysql_exporter_scrapes_total 92990^M$
```

is it some kind of a buffer? Anyone met such an issue previously?

Haproxy version: HAProxy version 2.8.1-a90123a, released 2023/07/03
exported version: mysqld-exporter:0.14.0-debian-11-r137

I tried:

- different metrics
- search by string, rstring
- manual verification that everything should work
- curl and telnet specific endpoint and it works like a charm

I expect that haproxy can fetch and find metric as supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by increasing buffer:

```
    global
      (...)
      tune.bufsize 123456789
```

adjust size to Your requirements, but be careful and read: https://docs.haproxy.org/2.8/configuration.html#3.2-tune.bufsize